# Moving data (JSON string) between webpages

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, wordpress

I have a WP website and am looking for a solution regarding moving JSON string between webpages without downloading the JSON string every time.

**Example**:
User visits the website: [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com). Once the website is loaded the JSON string will be downloaded from the server using php. User decides to click on the button that will open the webpage [www.mysite.com/offers](http://www.mysite.com/offers). In this page I want to show JSON string without downloading it again.

How can I achieve something like that? I already know how to download and show the JSON file, but I'm curious on how to send that string from on webpage to another.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to move data around client side is through cookies, especially if that data needs to be used all across the site. Javascript is the only way to do this without any server-side interactions.

A quick way to do this would be to set a cookie with the given js code:

```
document.cookie = "yourJsonString=" + encodeURIComponent(yourJsonString);
```

Then once on the other page, use the following code to extract that JSON string:

```
// a json object to store all the cookies in
let cookies = {};

// split the cookies up by the semicolons
document.cookie.split(/;\s*/).forEach(cookieStr => {
    // split those individual cookies strings into key value pairs
    let cookieArray = cookieStr.split('=');
    
    // add those key value pairs to the cookies json object we made before
    cookies[cookieArray[0]] = decodeURIComponent(cookieArray[1]);
});

// voila! there's your original JSON string on your new page
let yourJsonString = cookies.yourJsonString;
```

The `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent` are just there to make sure that your JSON string is able to be passed through as a cookie without any data being lost (i.e. having a semicolon or equals sign in your json).

More on cookies can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp